# Spark Framework puts HTML around my response

Tags: java, spark-framework

I have been trying to make a REST API for my bot, using the Spark Framework, which I personally like alot, and I wouldn't switch, but when I try to publish a GSON encoded POJO, but it puts some HTML around it, making it unparseable by other applications. Here is the result in inspect element: [image: the result]

and what I wanted to be sent was just the part in the <pre> tag, as I expected from my code.

Just to make it a bit more clear on what Im trying to do, here are my Spark Route and POJO I am turning into JSON:

```
get("/json", (req, res) -> {
    long sinceStart = System.currentTimeMillis() - Launcher.getInstance().getStartTime();
    sinceStart /= 1000;
    long hours = sinceStart / 3600;
    sinceStart %= 3600;
    long minutes = sinceStart / 60;
    sinceStart %= 60;
    res.type("application/json");
    return new JSONResponse(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + sinceStart,
            Launcher.getInstance().getDispatcher().getDispatchCount(),
            Launcher.getInstance().getDispatcher().getCommands().size(),
            Launcher.getInstance().getClient().getGuilds().size());
});
...
private static class JSONResponse {

    private String time;
    private int commands, servers;
    private long dispatchCount;

    JSONResponse(String time, long dispatch, int registered, int servers) {
        this.time = time;
        this.dispatchCount = dispatch;
        this.commands = registered;
        this.servers = servers;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public int getCommands() {
        return commands;
    }

    public int getServers() {
        return servers;
    }

    public long getDispatchCount() {
        return dispatchCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Launcher.getInstance().getGson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your `JSONResponse` you can try [ResponseTransformer](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#response-transformer)

Comment: @Cir0X currently I am doing this: ``get("/json", "application/json", (req, res) -> {...same...}, Launcher.getInstance().getGson()::toJson);`` But it does the same exact thing. Thanks for trying to help me anyways!

Comment: what does this image display? With what tool did you capture this? I do not think that spark java wraps your output in an html element. Have you tried to access your service with curl? `curl http://localhost:8080/json` and replace with the correct host and port your service is running at.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch That is correct! Oh my god thank you! It was just Chrome wrapping it in HTML. If you want make an answer containing what you said in the answer, and Ill mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: @ArsenArsen there you go ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of your service with a tool like curl like so:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/json
```

Spark java does not wrap the answer in html, so check, where the output you are looking at and where you took the image from comes from.